# Does $f'(x)\neq 0$ already imply that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am observing a differentiable function $f: I\to\mathbb{R}$ where $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a connected interval, with the condition $f'(x)\neq 0$ for every $x\in I$.

Now I am asking myself the question how "messy" a derivative can look under these circumstances.

I want to prove that such a function is already (strictly) monotonic (decreasing, or increasing).

The example

$f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto 1/x$ shows that it is necessary to have a connected interval.

I tried to prove it like this.

Let $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$. Now I want to show that $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(b)$.

Using the mean-value theorem, I have

$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(\xi)\neq 0$. Hence positive or negative.

Then $f(a)-f(b)$ is positive or negative.

The problem is that I would have to prove that this relation never changes for every $a,b\in I$. So once positive/negative means, always positive/negative, which is not immediate.

I can not come up with a counterexample to this, but this looks like it should need continuously differentiable, as $f'(x)\neq 0$ implying that $f'(x)$ is already always positive/negative seems like an intermediate-value kind off argument, and I wonder if you can walve this additional condition, when we have a connected interval.

With other words:

How messy can a derivative really look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the Darboux property?

Comment: No, I am googeling it up right now.

Comment: @EricTowers: The function in that answer is only a.e. differentiable.  If we allow that, then $f(x) = |x|$ is a much easier counterexample.

Comment: A better example for the necessity of $f$ being differentiable on the whole interval is $f(x) = x^{2/3}$. Can you see why?

Comment: @EricTowers: But I understood this question as assuming that $f$ is *everywhere* differentiable.

Comment: As did I. There is no mention or hint of measure theoretic ideas here.

Comment: @EricTowers: Yes, but that's the wrong inclusion to help us here.  Your counterexample is not in that subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuous differentiability is not necessary. The answer to your title question is yes. Of course, without continuous differentiability, we CANNOT invoke the standard intermediate value theorem on the derivative $f'$, because it isn't assumed continuous. On the other hand, derivatives have the intermediate-value property; this is known as [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) (for analysis).

Suppose for contradiction there exist $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$ such that $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ have opposite signs. Since $I$ is assumed connected, the entire interval $[a,b]$ lies in $I$. Hence, we may apply Darboux's intermediate value theorem to deduce that $f'$ must take on the value $0$ at some point in $(a,b)$; but this clearly contradicts the hypothesis.

Hence, we have either $f'>0$ on $I$, or $f'<0$ on $I$. In the first case, $f$ is strictly increasing (by mean-value theorem) while in the second case, $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Use  Darboux property.

Suppose, $f'(a) <0$ and $ f'(b) >0$ then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that
$f'(c) =0 $

In other way

You can also think,

Let, $a<b<c$ such that $f(a) <f(b)$ and $f(b)> f(c) $

Since, $f$ is not monotonic continuous function

There is $p \in (a,b) $ and $q \in (b,c)$ such that

$f(p) = f(q)$
Now, apply Rolle's theorem ,
There must be $x \in (p,q) $ such that

$f'(x) =0$
We get a contradiction.

Hope you got it.

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).